# How to change the default setting of a domain field in Grails to be nullable

Tags: class, grails, dns, grails-orm

I want any field to be nullable in default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the following in grails-app/conf/Config.groovy if you are using 1.2+

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable:true,blank:true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://omaha-seattle.blogspot.com/2010/02/override-default-grails-constraints.html)

> The defaults for nullable, blank and the other gorm constraints can be
>   configured in Config.groovy by adding a snippet such as:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable:true,blank:true)
}
```